# Laplace rule of succession for a Poisson process

Tags: bayesian, estimation, poisson-distribution

Suppose that I measure for an interval of time $t$ a Poisson process that has unknown average rate $\mu>0$ and I observe no event. What could be a reasonable estimate of $\mu$ from a Bayesian point of view?

Comment: As currently stated, this question is only answerable by re-stating Bayes theorem: for some prior, you can compute a posterior on $\mu$.

$$p(\mu|y)=\frac{p(\mu)p(y|\mu)}{p(y)}$$ where $y=0$, and $p(y|\mu)\sim\text{Poisson}(\mu)$.

Determining the posterior for an appropriate prior is left as an exercise for the reader, and the results are interpreted in the usual way. Are you uncertain how to interpret Bayesian inferences generally?

Comment: Could you add to your question to develop more completely what you are interested in? As it stands, the text contains no mention of repeated experiments, Laplace, or priors.

Comment: I guess my question is about the priors. Laplace rule of succession states that if we repeat an experiment $n$ times and get $n$ failures, the probability that next time we get a success is $$p(X_{n+1}=1|\{X_i=0;\, i=1,\ldots , n\})=\frac{1}{n+2}$$. This is based on the prior probability density function that expresses total ignorance of $p$ except that $0<p<1$. I would like to know what would be the continuous time version of that prior, if any. I.e. I would like to see a similar reasoning to that of Laplace rule of succession for continuous time Poisson processes.